# R loop over sqldf() and directory path

Tags: r, loops

I need to run a loop over some lines of code in which I use `sqldf()`

```
x <- c(9,11,14)
for (val in x) {
  name <- paste("sample_tb", val, sep = "")
  assign(name, sqldf('SELECT * FROM sample LEFT JOIN Data_1 USING (sample_id) LEFT JOIN Data_2 USING (sample_id) LEFT JOIN data_chronology USING (sample_id) LEFT JOIN data_chronology_2 USING (sample_id) WHERE data_id = val') )
  path <- paste("/My_Directory/",name,".xlsx" , sep = "")
  write.xlsx(name, file = path)
}
```

So my problems is that `write.xlsx()` now only creates an excel file with the name inside instead of the data. Furthermore, R doesn't seem to change the val inside the `sqldf()` either. Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Preface sqldf with fn$ and then use $val to indicate a variable to be substituted: `dating_tb <- fn$sqldf('SELECT * FROM date WHERE data_id = $val')`

Comment: Thank you. This works for `sqldf()` but I still can`t get it to run over `write.xlsx()`, do you know how to do that?